# ImportError: cannot import name 'sync'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

I'm trying to run the following sample code from [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync

# These example values won't work. You must get your own api_id and
# api_hash from https://my.telegram.org, under API Development.
api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
[root@server cli]# python3.6 client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 1, in <module>
    from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
ImportError: cannot import name 'sync'
```

I also have tried installing sync using the following command:

```
pip3.6 install sync
```

Any idea about the problem?

Comment: What happens when you use `import telethon`, `telethon.sync`? What is the traceback of the attribute error that throws?

Comment: Either your `telethon` installation is b0rked or you're importing the wrong file. What's the output of `import telethon; print(telethon.__file__)`?

Comment: The installation was broken! I tried uninstalling telethon and installing it again and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: This works for me.. **Check your development environment**
[![telethon install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab7Wg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ab7Wg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the package installation was broken. So, I reinstalled the package and everything works fine now.

Uninstall telethon:

```
pip uninstall telethon
```

And install it again:

```
pip install telethon
```